# Endianness of instructions

Tags: endianness

I understand about byte ordering for data but what about instructions? Let's say, a 64-bit instruction. How is it stored in memory?

I haven't been able to find any clarification on this. Everyone talks about endianness w.r.t to data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endianness is only sensible when talking about numeric values that extend over more than one byte. Instructions are not numeric values, so the concept of endianness doesn't apply to them.

It does, however, apply to multi-byte numeric values that appear inside instructions. For example, say you have an instruction "Load the decimal value 1,094 into register X". This contains a multi-byte numeric value inside it, 1,094. If the instruction is encoded as a series of bytes (as most CPUs encode instructions), then the concept of endianness would apply to how the 1,094 is encoded in the instruction. Typically this follows the CPU's data endian rules, but constants in instructions could (at least in theory) have their own rules. The documentation for the instruction set will specify how the constants are encoded.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Maybe I should not have asked about endianness for instructions. What I want to know is that if an instruction is 64 bits long, will the MSB be stored in lower address and LSB in higher address?

Comment: There is no MSB. Only a multi-byte number has an MSB and an instruction is not a number. This is why "1,234" has a most-significant digit but "1, 2, 3, 4" does not. There is only an MSB and an LSB where each component has some sort of weight that it's multiplied by before they're combined. If an instruction is encoded as, say, "0x34, 0x12, 0x9F, 0xAA" there is no weight that any of those bytes have and none is more significant (in that sense) than any other.

Comment: But let's say I am writing an assembler. How will I store these 4 bytes of instruction in memory? CPU must have a convention that 0x34 is at the lowest address?

Comment: @coder.in.me If you're writing down the number one thousand, four hundred and twenty three, the one is the most significant digit because it represents one thousand, not because you might write it down first if you write "1,423". Even if our convention was to write the number as "324,1", the one would still be the most significant digit because it represents thousands. None of those bytes represent greater quantities than the other, so there is no most or least significant. There might be some writing convention that you write the lowest address' contents first, but that is *not* endianness.